# looking for a sample code to read parameter value from aws parameter store

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

looking for a sample java code to read parameter store values like RDS connection string from aws parameter store. appreicate code or any reference links. thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html)

Comment: looks promising. so this requires injecting RDS params as environment variables while creating EC2/ECS task .am i correct?

Comment: Very precisely yes. Do you require something else too?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the V2 (not V1) example to read a specific parameter value from the AWS parameter store:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.SsmClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.GetParameterRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.GetParameterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.SsmException;

public class GetParameter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetParameter <paraName>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    paraName - the name of the parameter\n";

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
         }

        // Get args
        String paraName = args[0];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SsmClient ssmClient = SsmClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        try {
            GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = GetParameterRequest.builder()
                .name(paraName)
                .build();

            GetParameterResponse parameterResponse = ssmClient.getParameter(parameterRequest);
            System.out.println("The parameter value is "+parameterResponse.parameter().value());

        } catch (SsmException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was getting crazy because of not finding the classers in the libraries I was using... Had to do with me using version 1 libraries.

Comment: Amazon is strongly encouraging all AWS Java users use V2. V1 is no longer maintained. as stated in this Readme: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples.

Comment: I ran this program in my local. i have configured ~/.aws/credentials. Getting error : The security token included in the request is expired, when I run this program in my local.

Answer (score 9):

```
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagement;
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParametersRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParametersResult;
```

...

```
private static AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmclient = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder
            .standard().withRegion(System.getProperty("SystemsManagerRegion")).build();
```

...

```
GetParametersRequest paramRequest = new GetParametersRequest()
                .withNames(parameterName).withWithDecryption(encrypted);
        GetParametersResult paramResult = new GetParametersResult();
        paramResult = ssmclient.getParameters(paramRequest);
```

Comment: Upvote and accept if you found it answered your questions, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think GitHub may be of help. I searched for [SsmClient getParameter language:java](https://github.com/search?q=SsmClient+getParameter+language%3Ajava&type=Code) and some of the results seem promising.

[This one for example:](https://github.com/efenderbosch/discord-pogo-bot/blob/bd4118e13a022dc67bd9e112ce3e794799f34c53/src/main/java/net/fender/discord/DiscordConfiguration.java)

```
    public static String getDiscordToken(SsmClient ssmClient) {
        GetParameterRequest request = GetParameterRequest.builder().
                name("/discord/token").
                withDecryption(Boolean.TRUE).
                build();
        GetParameterResponse response = ssmClient.getParameter(request);
        return response.parameter().value();
    }
```

Comment: thanks.  i believe the new SDK has deprecated all these classes. i get class not found. error: package software.amazon.awscdk.services.ssm does not exist

Comment: I don't think the CDK is what you want to use. That's the AWS Cloud Development Kit and it related to creating infrastructure. You want to use the SDK, and the class should be under com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.

Comment: You want to use V2 APIs - not V1. The V2 client is software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.SsmClient;